# Can I damage my hardware TPM by improperly treating it?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

I read somewhere that TPMs are not hard to be rendered useless or broken by improper use of its API, considering I have complete user access to it via the command line. Is that true? Could you give an example of what I could do to destroy my TPM or my data by improper use?